# jQuery animate from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

is there a way to animate one element's height(let's say div) from bottom to top?
For example, let's say i have a div element with height of 15px.

```
<div class='greyBox'>
<p>Example text</p>
</div>
```

And the css is:

```
.box{height:15px;width:60px;backgroundColor:#000;float:left;margin-left:20px;}
.box p{opacity:0;}
```

I then use this jQuery:

```
 $('.greyBox').mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).animate({height:'50px'},700).children('p').animate({opacity:1},200);
     });
```

Now just add more boxes(red,blue...) with the same css applied to each. The animation is working, but if applied over let's say greyBox, it also animates the red one, which is next to him. I tried changing from float:left to inline block, but no luck.

Just one thing, all of these boxes are wrapped in a absolutely positioned div with width:100%, bottom:0;left:0;

P.s. I created a fiddle, so it can be seen firsthand. [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/BsPju/)

Many thanks,

Mirko

Comment: Create a jsFiddle and I'm sure somebody will help!

Comment: Ok here is the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BsPju/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $('.greyBox').mouseenter(function(){

   $(this).animate({height:'50px'},700).children('p').animate({opacity:1},200);
       $(this).siblings().animate({marginTop: '35px'}, 700)

   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BsPju/1/

You can counter-act the height by animating the `marginTop` of the sibling elements.

Otherwise you'd need to position them all `absolute`, with a `bottom:0` declaration.

Comment: Sure will. I used the `.siblings()` selector, so it will select all other boxes within the same parent.

Comment: Thanks, i really needed this. I knew it would work with absolute positioning, but it wouldn't suit my needs. This is great!

Answer (score 1):

If you change `float: left` to `display: inline-block` and add `vertical-align: bottom` to the divs, it displays the way you want it to.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/AVXLq/1/

Comment: Thanks, i did change to inline-block, but the vertical-align never crossed my mind. If i could mark both answers as correct, i would, but the previous answer is correct, so it was just a matter of seconds.